# How to create a log table in Hive to record job success/failure?

Tags: sql, hadoop, hive, hql

I want to create a table for logging in Hive. This table should contain basic details of a sqoop job that runs every day. It should list the name of the job/the table name to which the data was loaded using the sqoop job. The number of records ingested , whether the ingestion was successful or failed and also the time of ingestion.
A .log file is created after every sqoop job run but this log file is not structured to be loaded directly into the hive table using the LOAD DATA INPATH command.I would really appreciate it if someone could point me in the right direction about whether a shell script should be written to achieve this or something else?
Thank you in advance

Comment: you can prase the log files and fetch the records you are interested in.

Comment: I am sorry but can you elaborate more when you say parse the log files? I am not familiar with it

Comment: log file contains all the details you need, you just need parse that and put those entries in any table you have created